# What sorting algorithm used while overriding compare method of comparator interface?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections

```
 Collections.sort(ar, new Comparator<Intervals>() {
                      @Override
                        public int compare(Intervals o1, Intervals o2) {                
                                return (Integer.valueOf(o1.getEnd()))
                                        .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getEnd()));
                        }
                    });
```

Hi all, I have the above code in java. Here, ar is a list and Intervals is a class with 2 integer variables : Start and End. I wanted to know what sorting algorithm is followed when we override the compare method of Comparator interface as above. I know, by default Collections.sort() and Arrays.sort() use Timsort algorithm. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections.sort() uses a variation of [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)):

> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python
>   ( TimSort). It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting
>   and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth
>   Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January
>   1993.

Note that the `Collections.sort()` algorithms gets a "black box" comparator, and uses the value it yields for each compare - without caring what is going on behind the scenes of the comparator.

Comment: So, basically you are saying that, the sort() method gets a list of differences of integers here and then applies Timsort on it?

Comment: @priban91 No, it gets a list of your objects, and a comparator, that can say for any two elements a<b? a=b? a>b? It is the only knowledge it needs on the elements to apply the sorting, no need for the internals of the elements. Only access to the elements is done in the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

The Comparator and Comparable interface don't do any sorting, so there is no sorting algorithm there. They just compare two Objects, something you need if you want to sort a list of those objects.